# What do I need to do to install 21.10 with btrfs?

Tags: upgrade, backup, btrfs, 21.10

I’m currently using Ubuntu 21.04 with ext4 on an internal 2TB nvme drive (AMD Ryzen with no dual boot). I want to upgrade to 21.10 with btrfs. I’m assuming I need to totally wipe out 21.04 and do a clean install of 21.10 in order to go from ext4 to btrfs. If this assumption is wrong, let me know.

I’ll first do a Clonezilla clone of my main hard drive to an external drive (I've got Clonezilla installed on a USB stik). Also I’ll have multiple backups of all my user files (FeeFileSync and Restic). If you have suggestions re better ways to backup user files, let me know.

I’ll have Ubuntu 21.10 loaded onto a USB stick ready to install. I’ll select btrfs during the 21.10 install process.

What else do I need to do to help assure this upgrade goes smoothly? I’m a newbie and very much a beginner with Linux and very limited knowledge of the command line. What are the common problems that arise when doing this kind of upgrade?

(PS: I want to upgrade to btrfs cuz I’ve heard good things about btrfs fast snapshots and easy rollbacks. Also I'm an average user just browsing the web, checking email, working with some simple spreadsheets and not much else.)

Comment: Different distros have different focuses. I think the preferred alternative for ext4 in Ubuntu is zfs more than btrfs, in as much that Canonical have put in some support for the snapshotting features of zfs in various things. Fedora, OTOH, is more btrfs-oriented.

Comment: I'd agree with @muru, I've used `btrfs` for Lubuntu installs (as it's a QA-install *testcase*), but the result is just a different *file-system* on the disk, without any of the snap-shotting capabilities I have with an OpenSuSE install which expects *btrfs* as it's default *fs*. I don't understand your reference of *upgrade* as you're doing a *clean* install as I see it, then restore of your datafiles.. I'm very familiar with *upgrade via re-install* but that involves no formatting (you're going to format) so I don't see an *upgrade*. Snapshot restore capabilities will require setup I believe

Comment: Also FYI:    After a `btrfs` QA-test install; I usually follow up with a *full disk* install to remove it; as there are complications with some follow on QA-testing (as Ubuntu tools don't always automatically deal with *btrfs* as easily as they do other *fs*; the full disk install returns the system to a more common Ubuntu *fs* meaning I don't have to remember the `btrfs` is there & skip QA-tests that won't deal with it well... ie. complications can occur with *btrfs* & Ubuntu - so consider that in your choice.

Comment: Also asked at https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2469112

Comment: @muru You're saying the the btrfs snapshot and rollback features are not supported in Ubuntu 21.10? If that's true then btrfs is of no use to me. I'll just keep using Timeshift. BTW, I first tried Fedora 34 before switching to Ubuntu. As a noob, I found Fedora 34 to be a really awful experience; an endless stream of technical problems.

Comment: @guiverc I'll definitely skip btrfs if it doesn't play well with Ubuntu 21.10. I'm a noob so the last thing I want is to deal with technical problems that are way above my head.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't trying to say it "*doesn't play well*" or that there are issues with it, just *complexities* (I used the word complications) with using it. They can be worked around easily for sure with Ubuntu (and other *distros*), but are issues you won't see with systems that use btrfs by default (eg. my OpenSuSE example). I *format* in the QA-test example as the QA-tests don't make allowances for the *extra work arounds* required in subsequent install tests eg. a full disk *btrfs* install, if followed by a *install alongside* may not automatically show both OSes in `grub` which is a *fail*

Comment: @guiverc If I clean install Ubuntu 21.10 with btrfs, will the btrfs snapshot and rollback features work? Also, I don't understand anything you wrote regarding 'QA test install'. That was all above my head. I'm sure you're making valuable points and that is sincerely appreciated, but I'm a noob so they're above my head.

Comment: If you install with *btrfs* then you'll have a Ubuntu system that is installed on the *btrfs* file-system. You won't have access to snapshots/rollbacks until that is setup; in QA (*Quality Assurance*) testing the snapshots/rollbacks isn't tested for as it's not a default use-case (*people that want it usually know how to set that up themselves*). Myself I'd **not** recommend using *btrfs* with Ubuntu if you're not already familiar with it's use.  I've used *btrfs* with other distros (namely mentioned opensuse) but I still don't use it myself; I didn't think benefits outweighed costs for my use

Comment: `btrfs` works perfectly with Ubuntu. I don't have any problems.

Comment: It is a weird idea that something doesn't work, or "not tested" on Ubuntu. All features work the same way with any distros.

Comment: @Pilot6 I think I'll install Ubuntu 21.10 with btrfs in VBox and play around with it using TImeshift and other apps.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do a fresh install in order to switch from `ext4` to `btrfs`. `ext4` partitions can be converted to `btrfs` quite easily. I did that a few times. It may require some tinkering with `grub`, etc.

But if you are a newbie, it is much easier to do a fresh install. You'll need to choose "Something else" and select `btrfs` file system for your `/`.

The installer will automatically create `@` and `@home` subvolumes for `/` and `/home`, that is a convenient feature.

The only thing I would put attention to is swap. I would suggest to use a separate partition for a swap. Having a swap file on `btrfs` require some manual settings, like creating a subvolume for it. Otherwise you'll have problems with snapshots.

After you are comfortable with `btrfs` you can switch to a swap file later.

You may have some questions when using the system. Many already have been answered at AU.

Regarding backups of user files, it doesn't make much difference how you do it. You can simply copy them somewhere and later copy them back.

P.S. I am using `btrfs` for all my Ubuntu installations for quite a while (about 5 years).